# Magento 2.4 how add tabs ui_component in module custom adminhtml

Tags: layout, adminhtml, uicomponent, tabs

Good morning, could someone help me render some tabs in adminhtml with a custom module? I already managed to create the tabs, but the content is not displayed correctly, it is added in the same space as the tabs.
Thanks.

I am taking the sales module as a sale

[image]

Code layout
[image]

Code block render tabs

Comment: Please go through this link, I think it will work for you.
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/ui-components/components/tab/

Comment: thanks for your help